# Django next page not working in login page

Tags: python, django, authentication

I open my browser, and try to access my Django site. I'm logged out of my account, so I get redirected to my login page, with the page I'm going to as a GET parameter.

```
http://website.com/login/?next=/customer/7/54
```

However, when I enter my login information, I get redirected to:

```
http://website.com/
```

Even though, I'm trying to get to:

```
http://website.com/customer/7/54
```

/customer/7/54 points to a view that does have the @login_required decorator, but I was under the assumption, that it'd still point to that view after I logged in.What is going on?

EDIT: So I realized, I had a hidden input tag:

```
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value='/'>
```

However, how do I pass in the GET paramter '/customer/7/54/ into the login template?

Comment: When you manually navigate to `http://website.com/customer/7/54` does it appear correctly?

Comment: Are you using the built-in login view (`django.contrib.auth.views.login`) or did you write your own?

Comment: dgel: Yup.
aganders3: Using the built-in login view.

Comment: Can you post your login template?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to your edited question, you can get next parameter at login page as follows:

```
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}">
```

The standart django's `django.contrib.auth.views.login` passes `next` variable directly to the template context.
Also, read docs about [user authentication](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/):

> You can also specify the name of the GET field which contains the URL
>   to redirect to after login by passing redirect_field_name to the view.
>   By default, the field is called next.

But you, probably, don't need to change this.

Answer (score 2):

For people using their own view. You have to send "next" to your template

```
def login_view(request):
    '''..your logic..'''
    ctx = {'form':form,'next':next}
    return render_to_response('login.html',ctx,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your custom view function for login like this:

in `views.py`

```
def login(request):
    next = request.GET.get('next')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ...
        # if user logged in
        if request.GET.get('next') != None:
          return redirect(request.GET.get('next')) 
        return redirect('/')
    else: # request.method == get 
        return render(request, 'login.html', {'next': next})
```